# (Java) Libraries to generate C/C++/C# Call Dependency Graphs

Tags: c++, c#, c, dependencies, static-analysis

I'm looking for any libraries that could help me extract code symbols (functions, types etc.) from the C family languages, preferably including calling dependencies. A Java library would be best since it's a Java application I need this functionality for, but that's not a hard requirement.

My aim is to build my own generic model of source code of different languages which I'll do further analysis on. Do you know any such libraries? Could `clang` be invoked by Java code for this purpose?

Comment: Do you need one library that generates call graphs for *all* of those C family languages? Or just for Java? Have you looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_graph#Software and https://github.com/gousiosg/java-callgraph ? Ah, those don't include all symbols.

Comment: @mic They can be separate libraries to analyse each C language, but preferably to be used by a Java program. Thank you for the wiki link, it's quite helpful. The other one is for analysing Java code though, not C.

Comment: Oh okay, so you want a Java library to generate call graphs for C, C++, and C#, and you don't need call graphs for Java. (Wasn't sure if you were considering Java as one of the C-family languages you wanted call graphs for.)

Comment: @mic That's exactly it.